# Special name in SQL statement

Tags: sql

How do I use special name that was set in sql statement? This is my sql staement

`Create table KioskItem(Lock nvarchar(255))`

But I couldn't execute the statement due to lock being predefined name. So how do i make it so that Lock can be use as column name? As a side note, this sql command was executed in mysql

Comment: I suggest that you not use reserved words for column names, because over the long term all that quoting is a pain, and when you forget you'll get errors that make much less sense.

Answer (score 1):

Adding backticks to SQL reserved words will fix this:

```
CREATE TABLE KioskItem(`Lock` VARCHAR(255));
```

If you set the ANSI_QUOTES mode, as specified [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html), you can use double quotes too:

```
CREATE TABLE KioskItem("Lock" VARCHAR(255));
```

Comment: Juat a question i originally thought that was the problem but there is still error here? any idea what did a do wrong? This is my sql statement.                                                     Create table KioskItem(ID bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,BatchNo bigint, KioskID nvarchar(50),KioskInv nvarchar(15),TelcoID int,Prod int,SN nvarchar(50),RechargeCode nvarchar(255),RechargeAmt float,ExpireDate datetime,Available bit,SalesDate datetime,ReceiptNo int,"Lock" nvarchar(255))

Comment: nvarchar is not a valid mysql datatype - I'm assuming you don't need to deal with unicode chars at this point, so varchar will work fine.

Comment: i rectify that nvarchar problem but there is still an error. Create table KioskItem(ID bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,BatchNo bigint, KioskID varchar(50),KioskInv varchar(15),TelcoID int,Prod int,SN varchar(50),RechargeCode varchar(255),RechargeAmt float,ExpireDate datetime,Available bit,SalesDate datetime,ReceiptNo int,"Lock" varchar(255))

Comment: Can't tell offhand. What's the error? Try creating smaller tables first, then gradually add columns until you find the problem.

Comment: i try to recreate the table one by one and it is okay until when i try to add "Lock" column. the error said "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that coresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near "Lock" varchar(255). MySQL server version is MySQL 5.5

Comment: That would mean the syntax in my solution throws an error; does it?

Comment: Yes so is there something i need to add before i can add spcial name as column name? This table is a table i remake from MSSQL server that i use before this

Comment: If you mean using either '' or "", both of them still have' the error. Never mind. i found the problem already and i successfully create the table. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: make sure they're backticks `\`` (found next to the tilde) not single quotes `'`. Please accept my solution if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to use backticks " ` " when referencing the column otherwise you will get sql errors

for instance

```
SELECT `Lock` FROM table
```

Comment: the rpbolem occur when i creating the table. i havent reach the 'select' step yet

Comment: Yes I know - but when you do you will need it :-)